# Create actual C: root in tree with java

Tags: java, tree

How can we create a **tree application displaying my local C: as a root** and display it children node. I have visit several java tree tutorial and document on how to create such tree, but most of the tutorial and document show example on how to create tree with artificial folder and file, not actual file in local computer. Appreciate if there are plain code on displaying local C: as root as i learn quicker by visual and example :).

[image]

i just started my career and new to the world of software development. hope this question is relevant to SO community.

some site i had visited: [Oracle tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), [Oracle swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html), other

By the way i am using netbean.

Comment: Take a look @ the File api - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: For Java 7 (i.e. [nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: Well now i understand we have to integrate tree with file api. appreciate if there are plain code on displaying local C: as root as i learn quicker by visual and example :). by the way i had a long way to go. thanks guys